# Connect localhost database from azure function portal

Tags: azure, localhost, azure-functions

I am running my project, connected to a localhost database.
Its required for me to create an azure function for continue my implementation.
Is it anyhow possible to connect to the localhost db from azure function portal?

Comment: Not much specific to Azure Functions here. Your localhost has to be accessible from the internet to be accessible for Functions.

Comment: Maybe stating out the obvious, but do keep in mind (depending on your selected plan) your functions aren't running on the same underlying server every time they are invoked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your azure resources to connect to your on-premise resources you can take a look at [VNETs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet) or [Hybrid Connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections)

**note:** both are not supported in Consumption Plan functions, only dedicated plan functions.

If you are asking about local development of functions, then you can run functions locally on your machine while you are working on them and they will have connection to any thing on your local dev box. [See this for how to develop Azure Functions locally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local)